# Excel: Compare & find differences in excel that have CSV data

Tags: excel-formula

There are two columns in an excel sheet, these are having comma separated values, how to check if values in first column are present in the second column.

Three cases,

1. Exact match
2. Partial match
3. No match

You cannot use a simple match function as individual values have to be extracted from the csv cells, they may be in different sequences.

Below is one solution that has been tried.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, SORT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2), ",", "</b><b>")&"</b></a>", "//b")))

=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, SORT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(B2), ",", "</b><b>")&"</b></a>", "//b")))

=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&TRIM(D2)&",", ","&TRIM(C2)&","))), "Partial", "No Match")
```

Comment: Google Text to Columns feature in excel. Using this you can copy and paste your delimited  text onto another sheet and the delimted text would be pasted into separate columns. You could paste one column on one sheet and one colun on another sheet and then have a think about how you could use the match function (and is number function) in that situation.

Comment: Please share something we can reproduce.

Comment: Is a Partial match when in A1 a,b and B1 b,a or when A1 a,b and B1 x,a,b,x or both?